# VueJS: v-on:click not working on clicking the <button>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue app configured by NuxtJS.
I have the following template and worker methods that should be called upon clicking the button. But they are not being called.

```
<template>
    <button class="btn google-login" id="google-login" @click.native="googleLogin">
      <img src="~assets/google-icon.svg" alt />
      Login with Google
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPassword: false,
      checkbox1: false
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(firebase.SDK_VERSION);
  },
  methods: {
    googleLogin: function(event) {
      console.log('Reached inside the function');


      let googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      googleProvider.addScope(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
      );
      firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
      console.log(googleProvider);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have the method inside the `methods` object. I have tried multiple solutions `v-on:click`, `@click`, `@click.prevent` but none seem to be working

Comment: try with @click.prevent is it inside of some form ??

Comment: That's really odd, I think it should work - the only thing springing to mind now is that there might be another transparent element covering your button? You shouldn't need `.native` when dealing with base html element (unless you have component registered with name `button`?)

Comment: @BroiSatse I did inspect the element and no transparent element is above it

Comment: @Shantanu - any chance you could wrap it in a plunker or give a link to your repo?

Comment: What does console show when you click on the button while is `v-on:click="googleLogin"`?

Comment: This has been busting my balls since last night. It only happens in ie11 works fine in chrome. @shantau have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

`.native` event modifier is used with elements when you are trying listen any event happening in the child Component from the root Component.

For example you have a component `button-counter`, and your parent component need to listen to the `click` event happening in the `button-counter` component.

In your case you just neeed to trigger click event using `@click="googleLogin"`

**[Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)**

**[Read More](https://yossiabramov.com/blog/the-native-event-modifier-in-vue-js)**

**Sample implementation**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "MyApp",
  components: {
    'button-counter': {
      data: function () {
        return {
          count: 0
        }
      },
      template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    googleLogin: function (event) {
      console.log('Reached inside the function');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn google-login" id="google-login" @click="googleLogin">
    Login with Google
  </button>
  <button-counter @click.native="googleLogin" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to trigger the click event this way.

```js
@click="googleLogin"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).